# How to convert characters into ASCII code?

Tags: r, character-encoding, ascii

I need to translate a string of characters, for example `"Hello"`, into a string of numbers which is the ASCII numeric codes.

Example: `0 -> 48; a -> 97`, etc.

Does anyone know an R function to do this?  Hopefully, the function or piece of code will translate `"Hello"` into a numeric string like

```
c(72, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I guess you mean `utf8ToInt`, see the [R manuals](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/utf8Conversion.html):

```
utf8ToInt("Hello")
# [1]  72 101 108 108 111
```

Or, if you want a mapping of the letters to their codes:

```
sapply(strsplit("Hello", NULL)[[1L]], utf8ToInt)
#  H   e   l   l   o 
# 72 101 108 108 111
```