# strsplit not consistently working, character between letters isn't a space?

Tags: r, character, whitespace

The problem is very simple, but I'm having no luck fixing it. strsplit() is a fairly simple function, and I am surprised I am struggling as much as I am:

```
# temp is the problem string. temp is copy / pasted from my R code.
# i am hoping the third character, the space, which i think is the error, remains the error 
temp = "GS PG"

# temp2 is created in stackoverflow, using an actual space
temp2 = "GS PG"

unlist(strsplit(temp, split = " "))
[1] "GS PG"
unlist(strsplit(temp2, split = " "))
[1] "GS" "PG"
```

.
even if it doesn't work here with me trying to reproduce the example, this is the issue i am running into. with temp, the code isn't splitting the variable on the space for some odd reason. any thoughts would be appreciated!

Best,

EDIT - my example failed to recreate the issue. For reference, temp is being created in my code by scraping code from online with rvest, and for some reason it must be scraping a different character other than a normal space, i think? I need to split these strings by space though.

Comment: i can post with reproducible code, however this would involve posting the rvest() scraping code as well, which i don't mind, but wanted to see if we could find a solution without first

Comment: What happens when you do `grep(" ", temp)`? Then you can try `grep(" \t\n\r\v\f", temp)` to see if any of these whitespace characters work.

Comment: `grep(" ", temp)` returns `integer(0)`

Comment: You can see what your mystery space-like character is with e.g. `charToRaw` or `utf8ToInt` [How to convert characters into ASCII code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160958/how-to-convert-characters-into-ascii-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
unlist(strsplit(temp, "\\s+"))
```

The `"\\s+"` is a regex search for any type of whitespace instead of just a standard space.

Comment: also `[[:space:]]+` using POSIX regex

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment,

It is likely that the "space" is not actually a space but some other whitespace character.
Try any of the following to narrow it down:

```
whitespace <- c(" ", "\t" , "\n", "\r", "\v", "\f")
grep(paste(whitespace,collapse="|"), temp)
```

Related question here:
[How to remove all whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992082/how-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-string)